# Hill Climbing Algorithm - Optimum Step Size

Tags: predictive-modeling, optimization, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

I am implementing a standard hill climbing algorithm to optimise hyper-parameters for a predictive model. The hill climbing algorithm is being applied as part of a two-stage approach:

1. Apply grid search with large values applied to the hyper-parameter to find a 'best' starting point
2. Apply hill climbing algorithm in this space with a large number of different, random start points to find a local optimum

The large values that are passed in the first step, the grid search are

```
1*10^seq(-4, 5, by=1)
 [1] 1e-04 1e-03 1e-02 1e-01 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05
```

So I am struggling to choose an optimum step size that isn't too large that is skips the peak or too small that it takes too long to converge. I don't think a single value for the step size is appropriate for all values passed in the grid search since, for example the difference between `1e-04` and `1e-03` is vastly different to `1e03` and `1e04`. So I want the step size to be proportionate to the grid search start point. I know the search space I'm looking at is

```
grid_search_optimum/10 to grid_search_optimum*10
```

My question, therefore, is what is an accepted value for the step size in relation to the search space? I haven't found any opinions in literature around this and, in general, the only advice is to choose a step size that is "sufficiently small". Any advice or pointers to relevant papers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it worked for me that if the search space was know then annealing rate (divide the size size with number of iteration)helped to decrease/increase the step size gradually to get to local max/min but the draw back is it might get stuck in local and might need some "momentum" to go on, another draw back it it might be very slow.however it doesn't seems like the case with your question that you bother about it.

Please refer-
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep573/11wi/lectures/04-lsearch.pdf

This paper proposes self adaptive step size search-
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-34783-6_56

Comment: Hey BlackCurrant, thanks for the quick post! Do you have any reference for the step size being search size divided by the number of iterations? The paper proposing a self-adaptive step size is very interesting but wouldn't be appropriate in this case.

Comment: I have implemented annealing rate in context of gradient decent algorithms , if you are able to extend the concept here-
https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#anneal

few articles-
https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-algorithms-and-adaptive-learning-rate-adjustment-methods-79c701b086be
https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/

one in context of deep learning-
http://auai.org/uai2015/proceedings/papers/73.pdf

Comment: Sorry about the delay I was spending time looking through the attached! However, I am struggling to see how to implement an adaptive step size for hill climbing, how would the gradient be calculated in this situation?

Comment: Here is the article with code handy, i shall have to dug to find mine, basically you just divide the learning rate in each iteration by iteration  count. This is simple break down- https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-learning-rate-schedules-deep-learning-models-python-keras/

Comment: That makes perfect sense thanks! The only thing left unclear is the start value for the step size. In my problem the search space can vary massively so what size should the first step be in terms of the search space? I'm happy to anneal it thereafter as a good solution

Comment: Well that's another problem with learning rate which, its more over a design decision.It depends on case to case and its good to know where you are starting. More information you have about your current position the better. In Practice i  start with rather big one for quick convergence and then reduce it for less variance and stability, they key is the balance i guess.For starter you can try various and measure the convergence and choose the best one. however its not ideally if you have many parameters but for starters yes.

Comment: That reminds me there is line search also under adaptive learning rate, which let you decide how much it should change , unlike annealing. http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=gradient.descent#h2_lambda.

Comment: That's very interesting cheers for the pointers! I have marked the question as answered but if you do think of any papers giving an initial step size value in respect to the search space size it would be great to find one!

Comment: And If I am not wrong choosing the "right" initial size is an open research problem in DL. But I REALLY have to check my sources on this , not sure. This was one paper i had kept in to-read list a while back,https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7239593